# Visual Studio 2019 Installation Issue

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on Windows 10.

I have downloaded the web installer from the official site. Once I click on the installer, I get stuck on this screen, which says 'Downloading: 0B of 0B'

[Stuck on this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91EyN.png)

I checked the installation log, which shows below message.

"VisualStudio Bootstrapper:02/12/2020 2:50:48 PM: WebClient failed in 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer' with 'The operation has timed out' - 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer'.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:02/12/2020 2:50:48 PM: WebClient failed attempting to access https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer via 23.13.51.44
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:02/12/2020 2:50:48 PM: Download failed using WebClient engine. System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out"

I tried accessing the URL 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer' from Google Chrome, and the file got downloaded.

However, when I tried to browser the same URL through Internet Explorer 11, I realized that there is a redirect to 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9d2147aa-7b01-4336-b665-8fe07735e5ee/D6E0778F57A0F56302E6AD5B55B0423E148CCE2244A5D6047C3256E841052A23/vs_installer.opc'

The redirected URL is accessible through Google Chrome (It downloads Visual Studio Installer), but I just getting loading screen in IE, and I cannot open Developers Tools to check what the problem is.

[IE Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlS3S.png)

I'm assuming Web Installer is following IE's process, and hence cannot download the necessary files.

How do I move ahead from here?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I solved it by restoring default setting of windows brandmauer and turning on windows defender.

Answer (score -1):

According to the log you posted,

> WebClient failed attempting to access https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer via 23.13.51.44
> Download failed using WebClient engine. System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out"

Please check there have 3rd party anti-virus software enabled or enterprise group policy in place that might block the download. And temporarily disabling Windows Defender and\or Windows Defender Controlled Folder Access.

If you install Visual Studio behind a firewall or proxy server, then there are domain URLs that you can add to an “allow list” so that you have the best experience when you install and use Visual Studio.
Please refer to this document about more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2019#install-visual-studio